# I want to change the chapter name i.e introduction to upper case and want to reduce the spacing between chapter1 and chapter name

Tags: formatting, chapters

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1.25in,right=1in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Basics of CMOS Comparators}
    Comparators are most probably second most widely used electronic components
after operational amplifiers in this world. Comparators are known as 1-bit analog-todigital
converter and for that reason they are mostly used in large abundance
in A/D
converter.
In
the
analog-to-digital
conversion
process,
it
is
necessary
to first
sample
the
input.
This
sampled
signal
is
then
applied
to
a
combination
of comparators to determine
the digital equivalent of the analog signal. The conversion speed of comparator is
limited by the decision making response time of the comparator. Apart from that,
comparators are also can be found in many other applications like zero-crossing
detectors, peak detectors, switching power regulators, BLDC operating motors, data
transmission, and others. The basic functionality of a CMOS comparator is used to
find out whether a signal is greater or smaller than zero or to compare an input signal
with a reference signal and outputs a binary signal based on comparison.  The
schematic symbol and basic operation of a voltage comparator are shown in fig1.1,
this comparator can be thought of as a decision making circuit.
\subsection{<any sub section here>}

\subsection{Literature Survey}

\subsubsection{<Sub-subsection title>}
some text\cite{citation-1-name-here}, some more text

\subsubsection{<Sub-subsection title>}
even more text\footnote{<footnote here>}, and even more.

\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please copy your title into the real question and shorten the title correspondingly

Comment: `times` is outdated

Answer (score 1):

Warning: This will leave all chapter names in upper case characters.

The spacing between `Chapter Number 1` and `Chapter Title` is controlled in `\@makechapterhead`, there's a `\vskip 20\p@`, i.e. `20pt`, being hardcoded.

This can be changed by a patch, inserting some other length, which can be changed easily.

Warning 2: `times` is a deprecated package. Use `mathptmx` instead (but `Times` is also an awful font, in my point of view)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1.25in,right=1in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength\somethingdifferent
\somethingdifferent=10pt
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 20\p@}{%
  \vskip \somethingdifferent}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}{%
  \Huge \bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
}{}{}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Basics of CMOS Comparators}
    Comparators are most probably second most widely used electronic components
after operational amplifiers in this world. Comparators are known as 1-bit analog-todigital
converter and for that reason they are mostly used in large abundance
in A/D
converter.
In
the
analog-to-digital
conversion
process,
it
is
necessary
to first
sample
the
input.
This
sampled
signal
is
then
applied
to
a
combination
of comparators to determine
the digital equivalent of the analog signal. The conversion speed of comparator is
limited by the decision making response time of the comparator. Apart from that,
comparators are also can be found in many other applications like zero-crossing
detectors, peak detectors, switching power regulators, BLDC operating motors, data
transmission, and others. The basic functionality of a CMOS comparator is used to
find out whether a signal is greater or smaller than zero or to compare an input signal
with a reference signal and outputs a binary signal based on comparison.  The
schematic symbol and basic operation of a voltage comparator are shown in fig1.1,
this comparator can be thought of as a decision making circuit.
\subsection{<any sub section here>}

\subsection{Literature Survey}

\subsubsection{<Sub-subsection title>}
some text\cite{citation-1-name-here}, some more text

\subsubsection{<Sub-subsection title>}
even more text\footnote{<footnote here>}, and even more.

\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How many reputation did you get by answering that question so far? ;-)

Comment: This is different: It's a combination of `uppercase` and vertical spacing, but I would assume it's less than 83k ;-)